# awk with null record separator printing just one file

Tags: awk, null

How does the following code print just a single file?

```
find "$fdir" -type f -name "${fnam}-*.png" -print0 | awk -v RS='\0' -F'[-.]' '{print $(NF-1), $0}' | cat -vet
```

which gives me

```
04 /home/flora/edvart/docs/schimmel-04.png$
```

But doing `find "$fdir" -type f -name "${fnam}-*.png"` gives

```
/home/flora/edvart/docs/schimmel-04.png
/home/flora/edvart/docs/schimmel-05.png
/home/flora/edvart/docs/schimmel-06.png
/home/flora/edvart/docs/schimmel-07.png
/home/flora/edvart/docs/schimmel-08.png
/home/flora/edvart/docs/schimmel-09.png
/home/flora/edvart/docs/schimmel-10.png
/home/flora/edvart/docs/schimmel-11.png
/home/flora/edvart/docs/schimmel-12.png
/home/flora/edvart/docs/schimmel-13.png
/home/flora/edvart/docs/schimmel-1.png
/home/flora/edvart/docs/schimmel-2.png
/home/flora/edvart/docs/schimmel-3.png
```

Comment: What are the contents inside `$fdir`? and what is the value of `$fnam`?

Comment: For me works as expected (each file one record / line).

Comment: fdir: `/home/flora/edvart/docs` and fnam: `schimmel`

Comment: Is your (unknown) `awk` able to use `\0` as a record separator with the meaning you intend for it?

Comment: I guess `printf 'a\0b\0' | awk -v RS='\0' 1` may tell us something about your `awk`. Does it print two lines? or just `a`?

Comment: `printf 'a\0b\0' | awk -v RS='\0' 1` gives just `a`

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski It would print two lines with GNU `awk` or `mawk`, but a single line with Busybox `awk` or any other BSD awk.  The user here is probably using Busybox.

Comment: It is using mawk 1.3.3-17

Comment: @Dilna The same version of `mawk` in my Debian is not able to use `\0` either. This seems to be the culprit. Can you use GNU `awk`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only GNU `awk` and `mawk` (release 1.3.4 or later) can use `\0` as a record separator with the meaning "null character."  Older releases of `mawk`, BSD `awk`, Busybox `awk`, Plan 9 `awk` etc. all treat the string `\0` in `RS` as if `RS` had been the empty string, i.e., it enables "paragraph mode" (two or more contiguous newlines delimit records).